# Boolean algebra in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

Is there any way to use boolean algebra in JS?

Eg I would like to loop through an array containing true & false, and simplify it down to either only true, or false.

Doing it with boolean algebra seems like an elegant way to do it...

would like to do a comparison that lets me simply add the previous value to the current iteration of a loop

```
[true, true, true, true] // return true

[false, true, true, true] // return false
```

Comment: Do you mean 'and-ing' them all together?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think a simple solution would be

```
return array.indexOf(false) == -1
```

Comment: This won't work in ie7 or less, unless you define the indexOf function manually

Comment: This looks faster, but later on it could become a little harder to understand what is doing here.

Answer (score 17):

Try `Array.reduce`:

```
[false,true,true,true].reduce((a,b) => a && b)  // false

[true,true,true,true].reduce((a,b) => a && b) // true
```

Answer (score 7):

You mean like:

```
function all(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1)
        if (!array[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Or is there something more complex you're looking for?

Comment: +1 because it's simple, could easily be converted to handle a requirement of logical OR instead of AND, and it's essentially the same as the accepted answer that uses `.indexOf()` except it will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

```
function boolAlg(bools) {    
    var result = true;

    for (var i = 0, len = bools.length; i < len; i++) {
        result = result && bools[i]

    }

    return result;
}
```

Or you could use this form, which is faster:

```
function boolAlg(bools) {    
    return !bools[0] ? false :
        !bools.length ? true : boolAlg(bools.slice(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i < array.length;++i) {
   if(array[i] == false)
      return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

ES6 [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
console.log([true, true, true, true].every(Boolean));
console.log([false, true, true, true].every(Boolean));
```